# discord.py Why does command.before_invoke cannot access parameters of command

Tags: python, oop, discord.py

i am using the decorator discord.py commands.hybrid_command @**[beforeinvoke](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#hybridcommand)** to access the original command parameters but it cannot somehow access the parameter value

Lets assume i have this command called "setcash"
so when i used the command with my bot prefix

`!setcash 10`

original setcash command returns

```
@commands.hybrid_command(name='setcash', with_app_command=True)
    @commands.cooldown(2, 5, commands.BucketType.user)
    @track_speed
    async def _set_cash(self, ctx, amount: int = 0):
        print(amount)
>> 10
```

setcash.before_invoke returns

```
@_set_cash.before_invoke
    async def _before_invoke_set_cash(self, ctx, amount:int=0):
        print(amount)
>> 0
```

if i dont set amount to default zero, then it says parameters missing

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation, the `before_invoke` hook will only accept one parameter: a `commands.Context`.

To get the parameters passed in you would have to access them with `ctx.args`:

```py
@commands.command()
async def testcmd(self, ctx, amount: int = 0):
    await ctx.send("Test command")

@testcmd.before_invoke
async def before_testcmd(self, ctx: commands.Context):
    # This will print a list of *all* arguments.
    # In this case first the class (self), then the Context (ctx), then the amount.
    print(ctx.args)
```

Docs:

- [`Command.before_invoke`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=before%20invoke#discord.ext.commands.Command.before_invoke)
- [`Context.args`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=before%20invoke#discord.ext.commands.Context.args)